# Why this pattern with __FILE__ under preg_quote() is not matching the directory path?

Tags: php, regex, path, directory, preg-quote

This pattern with `__FILE__` under `preg_quote( $str, '/' )`

```
/^C\:\\xampp\\apps\\wordpress\\htdocs\\wp\-content\\themes\\themename\\inc\\fonts\/uploads\/[^\/\\]+(\/|\\)/
```

is not matching this directory path

```
C:\xampp\apps\wordpress\htdocs\wp-content\themes\themename\inc\fonts/uploads\BELLABOO\
```

here (just exclude `BELLABOO\BELLABOO-Regular.otf`)

```
C:\xampp\apps\wordpress\htdocs\wp-content\themes\themename\inc\fonts/uploads\BELLABOO\BELLABOO\BELLABOO-Regular.otf
```

But upon doing this with custom pattern, it is matching:

```
$pattern = '/.+inc(\/|\\\\)fonts(\/|\\\\)uploads(\/|\\\\)[^\/\\\\]+(\/|\\\\)/';
// $pattern = '/^C\:\\xampp\\apps\\wordpress\\htdocs\\wp\-content\\themes\\themename\\inc\\fonts\/uploads\/[^\/\\]+(\/|\\)/'; Not working!
preg_match( $pattern, $font_path, $matches );
echo $matches[0]; // C:\xampp\apps\wordpress\htdocs\wp-content\themes\themename\inc\fonts/uploads\BELLABOO\
```

How to make it work with the first pattern?

Comment: Can you share the value of `__FILE__`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the pattern:

```
/^C\:\\xampp\\apps\\wordpress\\htdocs\\wp\-content\\themes\\themename\\inc\\fonts\/uploads\/[^\/\\]+(\/|\\)/
```

With:

```
/^C\:\\xampp\\apps\\wordpress\\htdocs\\wp\-content\\themes\\themename\\inc\\fonts\/uploads\\[^\/\\]+(\/|\\)/
```